# jquery .load() does not load a table from xy.html but loads from xy.php (same table with same id)

Tags: jquery

So my question is the following, i want to load a table with id="tabla" into my php page from tapany.html, it does not work, BUT if I load it from tabla.php (the same table with same id) it works perfectly, why?

It would be great if it loads from tapany.html then all files would be in one file

```
$("#tapany").load("tabla.php #tabla"); <- the working one
$("#tapany").load("tapany.html #tabla);
```

Comment: you forgot the closing quote tag in the second example

Answer (score 0):

Turn this..

```
$("#tapany").load("tapany.html #tabla);
```

into this...

```
$("#tapany").load("tapany.html #tabla");
```

You should also be able to filter your results with jQuery Get(), like this...

```
$.get('tapany.html', function(data) {
  $(data).filter('#tabla').appendTo('#myDiv');
});
```

Comment: the quotation mark is there, like in the working one I just misspelled :)

Comment: are you sure that the ID selector lives on tapany.html, and are you sure you are working with tapany.html instead of tapany.htm? also make sure the html file is in the appropriate directory.

Comment: if you are using google chrome, open up developer tools and see if the console is giving you any errors.

Comment: I have already tried it, it does not indicate any errors, it says OK

Comment: The you need to triple-check the html document and make sure that ID really exist on that page.

Comment: when I load the tapany.html, for some reason according to the console it does not contain the table